# VS Code: How do I hide parameters in functions in outline?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Recently I did some C programs on my MAC (so I have to use vscode) and the functions in the outline box really made me feel suffer because the parameters in functions cannot be hidden which makes the outline hard to read.
For example, in source insight, a function: static int my_test_proc_write(struct file *file, const char *buffer, unsigned long count, void *data) only show the function name: my_test_proc_write in outline. In my c program, there are thousands of functions like this, and the outline box is really not good to read.

Answer (score 3):

If you disable the **Outline: Show Variables** setting, variables and function parameters will not be included in the outline.